# SQL Server T-SQL query optimisation

Tags: t-sql

I have a T-SQL query and I want to make it faster.

I have `Entity` and `Address` tables, and wish to bring back an address if a mailing address exists.

Sometimes there are multiple addresses for any given entity. There is a primary mailing address `tinyint` that sometimes is set and sometimes not, there's no rules here there could be 5 default mailing addresses all the flag set or none with the flag set.

This runs at around 20 seconds for 11k rows I really need to get this time down, can anyone help?

```
SELECT 
   e.*, addr.*
FROM 
   [Entity] e
   --Address does not always exist
   --PrimaryAddress is a Not Null TinyInt, sometimes this flag is enable twice for a given entity.
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   [Address] addr ON addr.[EntityID] = e.[EntityID] 
   AND addr.Code = 'MAILING'        
   AND addr.[AddressID] = (
       --This remove duplicates but add's a long delay(15 seconds) to execution time.
       SELECT Top 1 a.[AddressID]
       FROM [Address] AS a
       WHERE a.Code = 'MAILING'
         AND a.[EntityID] = e.[EntityID]    
       ORDER BY a.[PrimaryAddress] DESC)
```

It should also be noted that I can't add any indexes to the two tables either :(

Kind regards
Simon Jackson

Comment: It's a 3rd party database and any modification is not "supported".

Comment: @marc_s, there are often many viable choices to performance tune without changing indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified version of your query that I think will return the same rows. (Not tested). I can't say if this will be faster than your version. You tell me.

```
SELECT 
    e.*,
    addr.*
FROM 
    [Entity] e
  OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT TOP(1) *
                FROM addr as a
                WHERE a.Code = 'MAILING'
                AND a.[EntityID] = e.[EntityID] 
                ORDER BY a.[PrimaryAddress] DESC
              ) as addr
```

Comment: Thank you this has improved things, noticeably the first time it runs it was about 14 seconds, second time round, down to 2 seconds.

Comment: @Simon : use DBCC FREEPROCCACHE and so on to cleanup cache before runs

Comment: DBCC FREEPROCCACHE, oh dear, 23 minutes and 20 seconds with the outer, I'll my original one now.  There are a lot of layered views.

Comment: YOu have layered views? Oh dear, the vendor you bought this program from was incompetent weren't they? Have you considered buying a differnt program from a competent vendor?

Comment: OK, Here's the stats with this change using DBCC FREEPROCCACHE before each select.  
The original select, is consistently taking around 17 mins
While the OUTER APPLY has cut it down to to an average of 8 seconds, it's a vast improvement.

Comment: I really do like the simplicity of the syntax here it's very easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

You could stop using select *, you are returning the entity id twice and that is wasteful of both server and network resources. And do you honestly need every single one of the other fields? Eliminate any you don't need.  Select * should not be used in production code anyway.

You have a correlated subquery which runs row by agonizing row, try using joins instead:

```
SELECT     e.*, addr.* 
FROM     [Entity] e     
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT addr.* 
            FROM  [Address] a
            JOIN     
                (SELECT Top 1 a.[AddressID]        
                FROM [Address] AS a        
                WHERE a.Code = 'MAILING'          
                AND a.[EntityID] = e.[EntityID]            
                ORDER BY a.[PrimaryAddress] DESC) dedup
                    ON a.address_id = dedup.address_id) addr 
    ON addr.[EntityID] = e.[EntityID]
```

And again don't use select *, I don't know your fields or I would have specified them above.

Of course the real way to fix this is to fix the badly designed database. It should not allow more than one primary address (we enforce this through a trigger), then you wouldn't need the expensive remove duplicates task. I realize in your case this isn't possible, but it might make someone else think about their design flaw. Since this is a third party product, I would request that they fix it to allow only one primary address. Eventually if enough people complain, they might.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I tested your joins, and it's taking 6 seconds on average :)

Comment: I only added the * to keep things simple and focus on the key fields. Even then, the table and field names used here do not reflect the real ones, if you saw what I was working with then I fear the answers would be about conventions rather than the issue.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I've marked this the answer as it offered the fastest performance increase.

I do like @Mikael-Eriksson answer as well as its syntax is so simple, but it is a few seconds slower(in my query).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2005 or later version, you could try the following:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID ORDER BY [PrimaryAddress] DESC)
  FROM [Address]
  WHERE Code = 'MAILING'
)
SELECT
  e.*, a.*
FROM [Entity] e
  LEFT JOIN [Address] a ON a.[EntityID] = e.[EntityID] AND a.rn = 1
```

The result of this query would have one tiny difference over that of yours: there would be one additional column of `rn` with `1`'s and/or `NULL`s in it. I wouldn't consider it a problem, though, as masked SELECT lists are not recommended in production queries in the first place, and if that is a non-production script then one extra column will hardly be in the way.

References:

- [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

  - [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

- [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

  - [Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Or you could do this in a temp table instead of a CTE which can have the missing indexes put on it.

Comment: Tested this type of query, it got an average of 9 seconds. Thanks for sharing.